# Variable password in ConnectionString

Tags: c#, connection-string

I created connection string:

```
connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=abcdef; Server=123....; Database=abc; User Id=user; Password=xyz";
```

It works very well. I want to exchange password with variable:

```
connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=abcdef; Server=123....; Database=abc; User Id=user; Password="+textBox1.Text;
```

My program shows error:

> Login failed for user: user... (textBox.Text = "xyz")

Do you know how to exchange password with variable correctly?

Comment: What type of `connection` variable is?

Comment: I feel like the obvious question to ask here is *what's the difference between the evaluated second string and the one that works?* If they are actually equal, then there's something bigger and much more confusing afoot, and these details probably won't tell the answer. If they are different, that'll probably tell you your answer.

Comment: If it's the "something bigger" bit, then make sure you're checking each string to be *actually* equal, not just "they look pretty equal." Call `string.Equals` to make sure they are verbatim without any funky characters in there or anything.

Comment: Hi Eryk, it seems that you've modeled this to use a different connection string per user in your program... have you created a user in sql server for each user in your app, assigned rights etc.? If that's the case, I'd suggest you go a different way about this: use only one db user, and keep access rights management in your app code, do not delegate this to sql server. Otherwise you'll get maintenance headaches, and if there are a lot of users connecting to sql this way, you may be using more system resources than you'd like

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot to write, that this is an OleDbConnection.

Answer (score 6):

Use [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

```
static void Main()
{
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
    builder.Password = "YourNewPassword";
    string newConnectionString = builder.ConnectionString;
}
```

Comment: How do you know OP is connecting to SQL Server?

Comment: @Donal I don't know and OP didn't gave any clue about that. Replace it with `WhatEverConnectionBuilder`

Comment: +1. That was my first thought, but didn't know what kind of connection OP using....but idea is same.

Answer (score 2):

use `SqlConnectionStringBuilder`:

```
var csb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(<<your connection string>>);
csb.Password = "xyz";
string connectionString = csb.ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
connection.ConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=abcdef; Server=123....; Database=abc; User Id=user; Password={0}", textBox1.Text);
```

Comment: Thanks! That's work. I put also '@' before string, because of backslash in my Server name.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..

```
string strTextBox;

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    strTextBox= textBox1.Text;
}
```

You'd use strTextBox instead of textBox1.Text for the password.